# How to setup cypress on Jenkins - linux

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cypress

I'm new to cypress and I'm trying to configure cypress in jenkins ( linux server ). I already installed nodejs and cypress in server. But For some Reason I can't run cypress.

After setting up Jenkins ( freestyle project)
I tried

```
cypress run
npx cypress run
```

But nothing seems to work.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the NodeJS plugin in Jenkins and the NodeJS installation at global configs (Inside Jenkins). Then I prefer you install cypress globally in that. In addition, you need to run some additional dependencies for Linux/CentOS based systems. [cypress CI](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html)

For you to find the exact configs step by step, follow the link below. You will find everything you need there.
[Cypress Jenkins configuration](https://medium.com/@muditha_17849/configure-cypress-on-jenkins-ccf66a3b2366)

Comment: I have already added the dependencies. But I didn't add the nodeJS plugin. Will try that. Thanks  for the quick response and article.

Comment: I think Jenkins should know the Jenkins NodeJs installation path. To execute cypress. Once you add the NodeJS you can provide it.

Comment: That was it. Once I added NodeJS plugin and configured the path it worked without any issue. Thank you for the article.